# SVG get text characters bounds in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there any way to get the bounds of each character in svg using Javascript?

Note: All the text are in svg text elements (Not Tspan ... etc)

Comment: I guess those characters are under the same `<text>` node, right? Please, give the more info the better

Comment: Yes, thanks for your note I updated the question.

Comment: I meant if you have `<text>characters</text>` or `<text>c</text><text>h</text><text>a</text>...`. If it's the first scenario, I'm afraid you can't get the boundings of each character separately. Maybe you can get the overall boundings and then divide them by the number of characters, it will never be an exact answer, though. 
What is the purpose? Maybe we can find a more accurate workaround.

Comment: Yes it's like the first scenario.

Comment: @sailens you can get character bounds separately, no workaround necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an SVG DOM method called [getExtentOfChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getExtentOfChar) that will get you the bounding box of each character.

Pass in the index of the character you want to get, 0 for the first character etc.

```js
var t = document.getElementById("t");
alert(t.getExtentOfChar(0).width + " " + t.getExtentOfChar(3).width);
```

```html
<svg>
  <text id="t" y="20">hello</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note from that documentation for getExtentOfChar, "The calculations assume that all glyphs occupy the full standard glyph cell for the font", so it won't necessarily return tight boxes for each character.